# groupby contents of list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
d1 = {'id': ["car", "car", "bus", "plane", "plane"], 'value': [["a","b"], ["b","a"], ["a","b"], ["c","d"], ["d","c"]]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
df1
```

```py
    id  value
0   car  [a, b]
1   car  [b, a]
2   bus  [a, b]
3   plane[c, d]
4   plane[d, c]
```

I want to group my ids based on the contents of the values list. The order of the elements should not matter. After that, I want to order them based on the group sizes, so I get something like this:

```py
    id  value
0   car [a, b]
1   car [b, a]
2   bus [a, b]
```

```py
    id      value
0   plane   [c, d]
1   plane   [d, c]
```

I tried to transform my lists into dictonaries using Counter() and then getting the sizes of the groups. However I am getting the following error:

```py
import collections

df1["temp"] = list(map(collections.Counter,  df1["value"]))
df1 = df1.groupby('temp').size().sort_values(ascending = True)
```

TypeError: unhashable type: 'Counter'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the list to ignore the order. `list` type is unhashable, convert them to `tuple` then you can `groupby`.

```
for _, g in df1.groupby(df1['value'].map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)))) :
    print(g)
```

Output:

```
    id   value
0  car  [a, b]
1  car  [b, a]
2  bus  [a, b]
      id   value
3  plane  [c, d]
4  plane  [d, c]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer: does this solution also work, if you have strings (like "Tom", "Tim"…) and duplicates as list values?

Comment: it should work. Or do you mean to remove the duplicates from the list?

Answer (score 1):

Sort `value` column with converting to a string that is then used as a grouping criteria:

```
groups = df.assign(val_str=df['value'].apply(sorted).str.join(',')).groupby('val_str')

for _, g in groups:  # separate groups
    g = g.drop('val_str', axis=1)
    print(g)
```

---

```
    id   value
0  car  [a, b]
1  car  [b, a]
2  bus  [a, b]
      id   value
3  plane  [c, d]
4  plane  [d, c]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer: does this solution also work, if you have strings (like "Tom", "Tim"…) and duplicates as list values?